# JavaScript generated web page issue

Tags: c#, javascript, css, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with javascript generated web page. I have a web page on the internet that is generated by javascript. I am working on changing a web page using wpf web browser control. I have to make some changes to the web page by inserting jquery, and changing css and hiding some elements.

Here is the issue.

Application works ok most of the time, but sometimes, for reasons unknown, it does not change the css or hides the elements. I presume that it has something to do with the javascript that actually generates the page. My code is executed, but no changes are made, so I presume that the script cannot find the elements in the page because they do not exist in the page, at the time of the execution of my scripts. This is just an assumption.

I need help resolving this issue. I have tried delaying the execution of my scripts for n seconds, waiting for body.ready, document.ready and window.ready, but nothing helped. Also, I use wpf web browsers LoadCompleted event, but... From time to time, the script simply makes no effect on the page. Did somebody have this issue, does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 0):

When building single page apps, always use a framework like [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) or [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) together with Mustachejs (or Hogan.js) for templating.

Since we don't have any code to look at, if you're using jQuery, I suggest you check out `.live()` and `.on()` for attaching event handlers to elements you plan on loading into a div (making them clickable) etc.

Comment: I'm not building it from scratch, I just need to make some changes before showing it in wpf web browser, C#. I don't need to attach any event handlers, just execute it on start...